# Not getting value of first UITextField from UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitableview

In TagViewController.m I am adding tag to text field from cellview.xib

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    TagCell *cell = (TagCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TagCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.txtCellTag.tag = indexPath.row;
    return cell;
}
```

On Button Click I am trying to get value of textField with below function

```
(IBAction)btnSave:(id)sender {

    for(int i=0;i<[dataId count];i++) {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [[self tblImages] cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
        if(cell == nil) {
            NSLog(@";Cell is nil"); // Cell is always nil
        } else {
            UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:i];
            NSLog(@"Value is %@", textField.text);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting value of All Textfield EXCEPT First Row
First field value always coming as NULL

Comment: Is the row off screen? It's not a good idea to store state in cells as they get recycled and thrown away as they move on and off screen. You should pass the value up to your view controller as the user enters it. A delegate approach between your cell and view controller generally works well for passing data like this around.

Answer (score 0):

Better do typecast to UITableViewCell and get the textfield from the cell.

```
for(int i=0;i<[dataId count];i++) {

    UITableViewCell *cell = (TagCell *)[[self tblImages] cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    if(cell == nil) {
        NSLog(@";Cell is nil"); // Cell is always nil
    } else {
        UITextField *textField = cell.txtCellTag;
        NSLog(@"Value is %@", textField.text);
    }
}
```